# Selecionar linha da Kendo Grid quando clicar no hiperlink das colunas

Tags: kendo-ui

Estou com um problema na Grid da Kendo. O que ocorre é que eu tenho uma grid com várias colunas, dentre elas, tenho uma com a última posição enviada pelo rastreador. Essa coluna tem os dados em formato de hiperlink e quando clicado nele, abrirá uma nova tela mostrando a posição no mapa.

Até este ponto está pronto, mas quando eu clico no hiperlink e NÃO seleciono a linha da grid, simplesmente ele não pega a coordenada, pois ao clicar eu mando a latitude e a longitude da posição.

Em testes eu vi que seria necessário selecionar a grid no momento do click no link. Mas como faço isso?

Segue o código da montagem da grid:

```
$("#grdUltimasPosicoes").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
            {
                field: "Ignicao",
                title: "Ign.",
                template: "<input class='check_row' type='checkbox' #= Ignicao === true ? checked='checked' : ''  # disabled='disabled'/>",
                width: "70px"
            },
            {
                field: "Posicao",
                title: "Posi&ccedil;&atildeo",
                width: "300px",
                template: "<a href='javascript:Maps()'>#=Posicao#</a>",
                attributes: {style: "background-color: #= Cor #"}
            },
            {field: "DataEvento", title: "Data/Hora", format: "{0: dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", width: "135px"},
            {field: "DataGPS", title: "Data GPS", format: "{0: dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", width: "135px"},
            {field: "Rpm", title: "RPM", width: "80px"},
            {field: "Velocidade", title: "Vel.", width: "70px"},
            {field: "PotenGPS", title: "N&ordm; GPS", width: "95px"},
            {field: "PotenGPRS", title: "N&ordm; GPRS", width: "100px"}
        ],
        change: function (e) {
            if (this.select != null) {
                latlng = this.dataItem(this.select());
                Latitude = latlng.Latitude;
                Longitude = latlng.Longitude;
            }
        },
        groupable: false,
        sortable: true,
        editable: false,
        filterable: true,
        scrollable: true,
        pageable: false,
        selectable: "row",
        height: 250,
        dataSource: posicoes
    });
```

E esta é a função chamada para abrir a nova tela com o mapa:

```
function Maps() {
    acessaTela('HelpDesk', 'MapaPosicao', 'Novo', '1', 'Posi&ccedil;&atildeo no Mapa', '495', '650', VeiculoSelecionado + '|' + Latitude + '|' + Longitude);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade não é correto usar o [`change`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-change) nesse caso. O `change` é mais pra quando o usuário clica e seleciona a linha. Nesse caso, como o evento diz respeito à coluna em específico, não é certo usar a seleção da linha toda nele. Até vira uma questão de experiência de uso do usuário.

Eu prefiro registrar um evento depois de criada a grid, por fora mesmo:

```
$(grid.element).on("click", ".link", function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem(tr);
});
```

Onde `.link` seria a classe do seu `a` no template:

```
template: "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='link'>#=Posicao#</a>",
```

Agora, o que acontece no evento é que o [`dataItem()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-dataItem) também aceita um elemento `tr` da grid, onde ele pode acessar o `uid` da linha e achar o objeto no `dataSource`. Como o evento do clique está no `a` em si, usando o [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) ele encontra o `tr` respectivo.

Aqui uma [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/AYIZA).